# Importing and replacing an edited database via phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, wordpress, dns

I moved a wordpress site from one domain to another. I ran a total of 4 sql queries to replace the old domain name with the new domain name. 2 sql queries were successful and 2 were not. So, I imported the database onto my desktop and did a find and replace in notepad++. I then imported the database back via phpMyAdmin but I'm getting an error message. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

> Error SQL query:
>
> --
>   -- Dumping data for table `wp_comments`
>   -- INSERT INTO  `wp_comments` (  `comment_ID` ,  `comment_post_ID` ,  `comment_author` ,  `comment_author_email` ,  `comment_author_url` , 
>   `comment_author_IP` , `comment_date` ,  `comment_date_gmt` , 
>   `comment_content` ,  `comment_karma` ,  `comment_approved` , 
>   `comment_agent` ,  `comment_type` ,  `comment_parent` ,  `user_id` ) 
>   VALUES ( 1, 1,  'Mr WordPress',  '',  'http://wordpress.org/',  '', 
>   '2013-02-01 10:33:14',  '2013-02-01 10:33:14', 'Hi, this is a
>   comment.\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post's
>   comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, 
>   '1',  '',  '', 0, 0 ) ;
>
> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I only replace two entires, under the table "Options" there is 1 entry on the 1st page and 1 entry on the second page.

Comment: Looks like there is an entry with same primary key as the on you are trying to insert

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a complete re-import of the database, it would be worth deleting the whole database and starting again with the new, replaced code.

The error is because you have already imported the data, and it is trying to just insert the new data after that, causing Primary Key conflicts.

Comment: Ok. This is my first time doing this and I want to do I correctly. To delete the whole database do I: go to phpMyAdmin, and then click on the database over on the left. Then,check all the tables, then choose drop? Does that delete the entire database or just the contents? I guess after this I then choose the database name again over on the left and hit Import and choose the sql file sitting on my desktop.. Are they the correct steps? Thanks,

Comment: When clicking on the database on the left hand side you can also then go to operations and DROP Database, it is the quicker way. You then create the database again and then just import it, as you said.

Comment: when I click on the database and go to operations, there is no option for dropping the database. I see Create Table, Rename Database To:, Copy Database To, Collation. But no option to Drop.

Comment: In that case, you can probably just drop all of the tables and then re-import.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of your fields marked as your primary key in your DB.  You can't have two entries with that same primary key.

`1` is the value of that key MySQL is upset about.  By looking at the query you are trying to run, it looks like either `comment_ID`, `comment_post_ID`, or `comment_approved` is the key that you use as `PRIMARY` (based on those values corresponding to `1`)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to start with a new **empty** database, and then import your data from the old database.